# Get particular word from command line output in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to get the process ID of current running process. I have given the query and filtered the particular process using wmic command . But i am not able to get the process ID alone.

Is there any way to get the process ID as output alone ?

my output

Input: 
`wmic process where caption="tomcat6.exe" get commandline,processid | find "GxTomcatInstance"`

Output : "C:\Program Files\Apache\bin\tomcat6.exe" //RS//GxTomcatInstance001  5260

I am getting both processID and commandline , but I just need the process ID alone. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Hmmm, Your command explicitly asks to GET **commandline** and processid, but you only want the processid. I wonder what the solution is...

Answer (score 1):

generally to get the output of a command, use the `for /f` command.

The syntax is a bit tricky, especially, when `wmic` gets on board, but this should do:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%i in ('wmic process where caption^="tomcat6.exe" get commandline^,processid /format:csv ^|find "GxTomcatInstance" ') do set /a pid=%%i
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the commandline.

> wmic process where caption="tomcat6.exe" get **commandline**,processid | find